# Revolving door graph

Tags: graph-theory

How can I prove that revolving door graph $RD^d$ is $d$-regular graph?

$RD^d$ is bipartite graph in which the vertices are $(d-1)$-element subsets and $d$-element subsets of a $(2d-1)$-element ground set. Two vertices are adjacent if one of the corresponding sets is a subset of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First focus on a $(d-1)$-element subset $X$. In how many ways can you choose another element from the $2d-1$ elements to enlarge $X$ to size $d$?

Then focus on a $d$-element subset $Y$. In how many ways can you remove an element from $Y$ to shrink it to size $d-1$.

Conclusion?

Comment: $2d-1-(d-1)=d$, so $d$ ways.

In second case also $d$ ways.

So is that enough to prove it?

Comment: Yes, we have shown that every element has $d$ edges to other elements. But the fact that you ask this question shows that you have not yet properly mastered the concepts involved. Do some more study until you thoroughly understand this, then write your own proof.

Comment: Is that standard terminology? How is that graph like a revolving door?

Comment: Try to change one subset into another one (using a path on the graph). You have to change one element at a time.